# How to display other user's show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an admin page in my application with a list of all user's emails. When I click the email's link, I want to view that user's profile. I am getting the right URL, but my if statement won't render the user's profile since it's checking if the page is the current_user. How do I have it display the user's profile that is connected to the email?

Here is my code currently:

```
<% if current_page?(current_user) %>
    <% render 'users/show' %>
```

I need something like this but it won't work:

```
<% if current_page?('/users/id#') %>
    <% render 'users'show' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the options: controller, action and other params

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: current_user.id) %>
  <%= render 'users/show' %>
```

You can also make use of route helpers

```
<% if current_page?(user_path(current_user)) %>
  <%= render 'users/show' %>
```

Comment: Both of these work for me when I type the URL of which user I want to go to like: /users/1 or users/2 ---> but they don't work when I go to my user index page: /users/ ---> I get a URLGenerationError id:nil

Comment: So just remove the `id` then

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'users' && params[:id] == curent_user.id %>
  <%= render 'users/show' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the options: controller, action and other params

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: current_user.id) %>
  <%= render 'users/show' %>
```

Comment: This is only displaying the current_user's profile page but not rendering any of the other users. I don't know what to put for the id:

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this:

```
<% if current_user && current_page?(user_path(current_user)) %>
  <%= render 'users/show' %>
```

It will check if there is a connected user and check if this is the correct page.